# Help with column editor in a data grid!

Tags: c#

I have a two different data sources that share one data grid. I have a column editor that allows the user to pick which columns they want to see. This works except, when I change the datasource, the columns change back to to what they started. i want the columns to stay the same as the user the picked them. Any help? thanks

Comment: If you post some example code that will give people wishing to help something to go on.

Answer (score 1):

Did you remember to set the AutoGenerateColumns property to false?

Comment: If I change the autogenerate columns to false, I see no headers at all. I do not have fixed headers.

Comment: Then we've identified the problem. You must set AutoGenerateColumns to false and add explicit column definitions. Since you are allowing the user to customize the grid columns, you will have to do this in code using the Columns collection of the data grid. You'll also have to store the user selected columns in a session variable as noted by MAW74656 so you can persist the user's selections across postbacks.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like the page is posting back and reverting to initial settings.  You can put the gridview in an asp.net ajax updatepanel to prevent anything else on the page from changing.

Or you could store the columns in session variables whenever they change and read them then set the proper columns in the page_load event if its a postback.

Comment: No, although there might be something similiar in your framework.  What are you working in?

Comment: Is this a web form?  Or is it a winform?  Or something else?  If its a winform, you can save the values in a variable (variables), and then after you databind(), set them again.

Comment: Its a WPF project. Basically, I have a combo box which has several different selections in it. If i click on one of the items in the combo box and change the column headers and then change to another item, the headers change back to the default. I want the headers to stay the same no matter item i choose.